# JAVA - Netbeans - Ciclo FOR

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

Estoy comenzando en lenguaje java, con netbeans.
Realizo algunos ejercicios, solo no logro comprender cómo funciona el siguiente ciclo:

```
if (num<=1){
        return false;
    }else{
        int prueba;         
        int contador=0;
        prueba=(int)Math.sqrt(num);
        for (;prueba>1;prueba--){
            if (num%prueba==0){
                contador+=1;
            }
        }
        return contador < 1;
    }
```

Comment: Cuando tengas que presentar código, no lo coloques en forma de foto, utiliza el botón "{}" ubicado en la parte superior de la parte donde creas o editas tu pregunta, esto ayuda para cuando alguien te conteste, no tenga que poderse a digitar todo tu código en caso de que tenga que explicar algo específico. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Está mirando si `prueba` tiene divisores.

El `for` clásico tiene 3 "secciones":

- definición e inicialización de variables;
- una expresión que devuelve `boolean` que indica si se tiene que continuar iterando;
- acciones a hacer al final de cada bucle.

En tu caso

```
for (;prueba>1;prueba--){
```

- no hay definición ni inicialización de variables, se usan variables definidas antes;
- se iterarará mientras `prueba` sea mayor que 1;
- después de cada iteración se restará 1 a `prueba` (así que en algún momento `prueba` acabará siendo `1` o menor).

La condición

```
if (num%prueba==0){
```

comprueba si la operación módulo `%` (el "resto" de la división) devuelve 0. Si es así, `prueba` es un divisor de `num`.

Por último,

```
prueba=(int)Math.sqrt(num);
```

Si `prueba` tiene algún divisor, algunos de estos han de estar entre `1` y raiz cuadrada de `prueba`de hecho la mitad exacta de los divisores, salvo en el caso de los cuadrados perfectos. Al iniciar `prueba` con este valor, si existe algún divisor el valor de `contador` será `1` o mayor, si no existe será `0`.